# Adding Foreign Key Fails in MySQL - errno 150 - using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

UPDATE: Darn - wouldn't you know it that the minute I posted I got the aha! The main table needs to come first in the creation.

UPDATE 2: For anyone following, the problem was with my mysqldump command containing the --compact option. This removed the mysqldump feature of including FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; at the top of the dump file. Now with compact removed, the problem is completely solved. No need to manually insert this in my dump file.

Can I specify the order of tables when doing a mysqldump?

I am uploading localhost MySQL database to my shared server. I get the following error trying to re-create a table with a foreign key .  "#1005 - Can't create table 'username_test.gemdetail' (errno: 150)" The sql statement is below. When the Constraint clause is removed, the tables import just fine)

From the MySQL - FOREIGN KEY Constraints Documentation:
If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error message.

I've checked for the following conditions (correct me please if I've missed something):

1) The two tables must be ENGINE=InnoDB.  - YES
2) The two tables must have the same charset. - YES
3) The PK column(s) in the parent table and the FK column(s) must be the same data type. - YES
4) The PK column(s) in the parent table and the FK column(s), if they have a define collation type, must have the same collation type; - NOT DEFINED
5) If there is data already in the foreign key table, the FK column value(s) must match values in the parent table PK columns. - NO DATA
6) And the child table cannot be a temporary table. - N/A

I've also tried importing to a new empty database. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

The relevant part of the sql code that mysqldump generates (I've removed other columns & keys for readability sake but this stripped down code produces the same result):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gemdetail`;
CREATE TABLE `gemdetail` (
  `gemdetailid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gemid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gemdetailid`),
  KEY `gemid` (`gemid`),
  CONSTRAINT `gemdetail_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`gemid`) REFERENCES `gems` (`gemid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=875 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gems`;
CREATE TABLE `gems` (
  `gemid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gemid`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=528 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Lastly the Database version info:

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Software: MySQL
Software version: 5.5.32-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL) (BetterLinux 01 Sep 5 2013 23:04:40)
Protocol version: 10

Comment: Yes sometime we don't always know what the real question is. As for being unclear, @Filipe Silva was able to give the answer without creating a whole new question. As in other posts, anyone searching on this problem often has these issues combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create table gems first, since you are referencing it in gemdetail table, so it has to exist:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gems`;
CREATE TABLE `gems` (
  `gemid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gemid`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=528 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gemdetail`;
CREATE TABLE `gemdetail` (
  `gemdetailid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gemid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gemdetailid`),
  KEY `gemid` (`gemid`),
  CONSTRAINT `gemdetail_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`gemid`) REFERENCES `gems` (`gemid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=875 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acc1e)</kbd>

To create the tables after a mysqldump and not give errors for foreign keys, open the dump file put this statement at the beginning:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Comment: Yes, that is the final solution and what solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I meant to just give it a one point thumbs up (he was seconds behind you). I've corrected it. Thanks again.

Comment: I was able to solve this without having to edit the dump file each time. I removed the --compact option from the mysqldump command.

Answer (score 1):

you should create "gems" before "gemdetail", switch create queries.

Comment: I got the aha! answer the second after I posted. Thanks for replying quickly. Now the question is can I use mysqldump to place the order of the tables correctly? Currently I use: mysqldump -h localhost -u user -ppassword --compact --add-drop-table --quick dbname >dump.sql

Comment: sorry, I haven't heard something for such as thing... I searched a bit but there is nothing for this...

disabling foreign_key_checks only makes your insert queries faster, it is not for ignoring create problems

Comment: It's faster insertions *and* the ability to create tables in any order: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html ...  Missing targets of foreign key constraints are silently allowed while mismatches (e.g. against a column of a different data type) will still throw an error.

Comment: yes you are right, i was wrong. I learned a bit more :) thank you for information.